# flexbox stretching height of element with a difficult layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div>#banner</div>
    <div>#left-panel</div>
    <div>#content</div>
    <div>#footer</div>
</div>
```

[image: The element placements]

I am fairly new to flex, and was wondering I can achieve the following result:

- ## page-wrapper is 100% height and width
- ## left-panel (defined width) is stretched to 100% width of #page-wrapper
- ## banner (defined height), #content, and #footer (defined height) together totals the height of the #left-panel and is stretched horizontally to cover any remaining spaces

If someone could please guide me through or know any tutorials out there that I can follow to achieve this.

Comment: Don't include an image - add the complete html/css you have (much better - create a demo in jsfiddle/snippet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help:
https://jsfiddle.net/wbncm2j4/1/

```css
#page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
#left-panel {
  background: #BBB;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  order: -1;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#banner, #footer, #content {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
#banner {
  background: #99C;
  height: 40px;
}
#footer {
  background: #C9C;
  height: 25px;
}
#content {
  background: #9C9;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="banner">banner</div>
    <div id="left-panel">left-panel</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

`flex-flow: column wrap;` and 100% height to left-panel.
Then set the height of the header & footer.
Use `order` to change the order in which the elements appear.

Comment: When I try this...if the left panel has more content than the #content, the height still does not stretch. I believe the 100% height to #left-panel is causing this.

Comment: Changed to `min-height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `flex-direction: column` on parent element and make `left-panel` element take 100% of height.

```css
#page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#page-wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  width: 80%;
}
#page-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 20%;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>#banner</div>
  <div>#left-panel</div>
  <div>#content</div>
  <div>#footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what does  flex: 0 0 100%; do? Can you please help me understand?

Comment: @webkitfanz it is similar to height: 100%(where flex-flow:column, else it is width:100% ) and force next content to draw a new col :)

Comment: It is shorthand for flex `grow`, `shrink` , `basis`, you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: But you #content part doesn't strectch by the way ;) , banner, content and footer shares evenly the col they live in with your code :p

Answer (score 0):

You may use `flex-grow` and `flex-wrap` to achieve this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
div div {
  /* basic CSS and see them */
  width: 80vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;
  padding: 1em;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
  /* reorder place in the flow defaut is 0; -1 put the element in front all  */
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100%;
  /* next element will show in next column */
  background:turquoise
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;/* or flex-grow:1; the short hand propertie works fine through the different browsers */
  /* will take whole space avalaible*/
  background:tomato
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>#banner</div>
  <div>#left-panel</div>
  <div>#content</div>
  <div>#footer</div>
</div>
```